# How can I speedup Java web application compilation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, compilation

I have just started work on an existing Java web application and I find that it takes about 5-10 minutes for the application to compile and run. What are the common ways to reduce this time? It is my first time working on an application of this size. I am used to coding and testing incrementally and find this wait unbearable.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I am using Maven as my build system.

Comment: It might be useful to know some of the frameworks you are using, if the application is layered (i.e. a DAO/DTO layer and a web layer), the container your testing in, etc.

All these play into compilation time and you might find some tips from people experienced with optimizing what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiate *the build*, and *building during development*.

- For the build use a dedicated build system, like Maven or Ant.
- For building during development setup your IDE to automatically compile classes (on save) and send them directly on your application server / servlet-container, so that they are hot-swapped.

Thus it won't matter how long does it take to make the build.

As of how to reduce the build-time, it depends on the build-technology you are using.